# Active Record Query Interface. Count, Join & Group

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get all the movies sorted by the number of likes (even if they dont have likes yet). I have the following working sql statement:

```
      SELECT *, COUNT(case when movie_votes.like = 1 then 1 end) AS count_likes 
      FROM movies 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_votes  
      ON movie_votes.movie_id = movies.id 
      GROUP BY movie_id 
      ORDER BY count_likes;
```

And I want to implement it in my controllers. So far I have:

```
      Movie.select("*, COUNT(case when 'movie_votes'.'like'=1 then 1 end) AS         count_likes").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN 'movie_votes' ON 'movies'.'id'='movie_votes'.'movie_id'").group("'movie_id'")
```

Which outputs form console:

```
     SELECT *, COUNT(case when 'movie_votes'.'like'=1 then 1 end AS count_likes FROM `movies` LEFT OUTER JOIN 'movie_votes' ON 'movie'.'id'='movie_votes'.'movie_id' GROUP BY 'movie_id'
```

AND an Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
Am I doing something wrong no the syntax?

Comment: Closing bracket after end is missing

Comment: Thank Rajesh! But I am still geting an error..

Comment: can you share the schema of movies and movie_votes?

Answer (score 0):

For those who might find this useful:

```
    scope :order_by_likes_or_hates, lambda {|type| 
        select("*, COUNT(case when movie_votes.like=#{type} then 1 end) AS count_likes").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_votes ON movies.id=movie_votes.movie_id").group("movie_votes.movie_id").order("count_likes DESC")}
```

If someone could provide a cleaner version please do.